# Python failing to install package: Visual Studio Build Tools failed with exit code 2

Tags: python, visual-c++, pip

I am trying to install the pIMZ packge from Github (https://github.com/mjoppich/pIMZ). My operating system is Windows 10 and I am using the Anaconda/Conda environment (Python 3.7.11).
The installation crashes when I reach "Building wheels for collected packages: pIMZ"
I have tried the following:

- pip install --upgrade wheel
- pip install pIMZ --no-cache-dir
- Installing Visual Studio Build Tools including:

  - Desktop development with C++
  - C++/CLI support
  - VS 2019 C++ build tools
  - VS 2017 C++ build tools
  - VS 2015 C++ build tools
  - Win10SDK 10
- Running the pip install from the Visual Studio Build Tools Developer Command Prompt

I am not sure what to try next. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: pIMZ
  Building wheel for pIMZ (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [120 lines of output]
      .
      ['.\\cIMZ/segment.cpp']
      E:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:760: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        % (opt, underscore_opt)
      E:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:516: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0a' to '1.0a0'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\annotations.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\clustering.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\comparative.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\differential.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\hubmap_downloader.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\imzml.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\plotting.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\regions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      running egg_info
      creating pIMZ.egg-info
      writing pIMZ.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pIMZ.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pIMZ.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pIMZ.egg-info\top_level.txt
      writing manifest file 'pIMZ.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest file 'pIMZ.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'pIMZ.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tablefilter.js -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tablefilter.js.map -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tf-1-d93e97e989b71a9f7e7e.js -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tf-1-d93e97e989b71a9f7e7e.js.map -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\colsVisibility.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\filtersVisibility.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\tablefilter.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\blank.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_filter.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\downsimple.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_clp.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_exp.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_filter.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_filterActive.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\upsimple.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\default.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\bg_infDiv.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\bg_th.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_eraser.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_eraser.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\mytheme.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\bg_headers.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\bg_infDiv.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_filter.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\skyblue.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\bg_skyblue.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_prev_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\icn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\transparent.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_prev_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\icn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      running build_ext
      building 'pIMZ.libPIMZ' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\cIMZ
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\cIMZ\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IE:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\include -IE:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tp.\cIMZ/segment.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\.\cIMZ/segment.obj -std=c++1z -Wall -fopenmp -fPIC -std=gnu++17 -O3
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++1z'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu++17'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
      segment.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdint.h(18): error C2371: 'int8_t': redefinition; different basic types
      C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-zxyjziiu\cIMZ\./src/srm.h(6): note: see declaration of 'int8_t'
      C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-zxyjziiu\cIMZ\src\imageregion.h(45): warning C4820: 'ImageRegion': '3' bytes padding added after data member 'ImageRegion::m_iDims'
      .\cIMZ/segment.cpp(36): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pIMZ
  Running setup.py clean for pIMZ
Failed to build pIMZ
Installing collected packages: pIMZ
  Running setup.py install for pIMZ ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for pIMZ did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [120 lines of output]
      .
      ['.\\cIMZ/segment.cpp']
      E:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:760: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_file' instead
        % (opt, underscore_opt)
      E:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py:516: UserWarning: Normalizing '1.0a' to '1.0a0'
        warnings.warn(tmpl.format(**locals()))
      running install
      E:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\annotations.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\clustering.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\comparative.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\differential.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\hubmap_downloader.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\imzml.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\parser.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\plotting.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\regions.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      copying pIMZ\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ
      running egg_info
      writing pIMZ.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pIMZ.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to pIMZ.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to pIMZ.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pIMZ.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'pIMZ.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tablefilter.js -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tablefilter.js.map -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tf-1-d93e97e989b71a9f7e7e.js -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\tf-1-d93e97e989b71a9f7e7e.js.map -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\colsVisibility.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\filtersVisibility.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\tablefilter.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\blank.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_filter.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\downsimple.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_clp.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_exp.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_filter.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\icn_filterActive.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\upsimple.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\default.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\bg_infDiv.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\bg_th.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_eraser.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_eraser.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_over_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\default\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\mytheme.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\bg_headers.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\bg_infDiv.jpg -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_filter.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\btn_previous_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\mytheme\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\skyblue.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\bg_skyblue.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\btn_prev_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\icn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\skyblue\images
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\transparent.css -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent
      creating build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_first_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_last_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_next_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\btn_prev_page.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\icn_clear_filters.png -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      copying pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images\img_loading.gif -> build\lib.win32-cpython-37\pIMZ\tablefilter\style\themes\transparent\images
      running build_ext
      building 'pIMZ.libPIMZ' extension
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\cIMZ
      creating build\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\cIMZ\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IE:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\include -IE:\Users\Jelle\Anaconda3\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tp.\cIMZ/segment.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win32-cpython-37\Release\.\cIMZ/segment.obj -std=c++1z -Wall -fopenmp -fPIC -std=gnu++17 -O3
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++1z'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fPIC'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=gnu++17'
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-O3'
      segment.cpp
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\stdint.h(18): error C2371: 'int8_t': redefinition; different basic types
      C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-zxyjziiu\cIMZ\./src/srm.h(6): note: see declaration of 'int8_t'
      C:\Users\Jelle\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-zxyjziiu\cIMZ\src\imageregion.h(45): warning C4820: 'ImageRegion': '3' bytes padding added after data member 'ImageRegion::m_iDims'
      .\cIMZ/segment.cpp(36): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pIMZ

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```